# Android Gyroscope readings Issue

Tags: android, android-sensors, gyroscope, android-version

I was working on an app which utilizes the gyroscope readings from the device. 
All devices give correct readings except for samsung galaxy S3(GT-I9300 android 4.1.2). The gyroscope reading saturates at about 10rad/s with a flat curve in the graph for it where as the reading for other devices would spike up more(17-25rad/s)  without any flat curve.
I tried running one of the sensor monitoring app(Sensor Kinetics) and got the same graph. Please find the link to screenshots.

[Samsung galaxy S3 GT-I9300 Android Version 4.1.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n04EW.png)

[Samsung galaxy S3 SGH-I747 Android Version 4.1.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwGqn.png)

Can anyone please help me identify the root cause of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to identify the root cause behind the issue. 
The above listed samsung devices use different Sensor manufacturers with different range of the readings for gyroscope.

For the GT-I9300 version the range was around 10rad/s around which the reading was halting where as the other version has a range almost double of it.

GT-I9300  :
Manufacturer: STMicroelectronics.
Range: +-500deg/s

SGH-I747  :
Manufacturer: InvenSense
Range: +-1000deg/s